# How to print/log array of string in java?

Tags: java, string, object

Little Background:

I have `csv` file which has lots of rows and each row has string elements, one example of such a row would be

```
String[] data = [20,11,Clothing,TShirts,Abercombie,Gap]

data.toString() = [Ljava.lang.String;@1152e94]
```

Now in my parser, I am parsing this csv file and getting each row present in the file as 
`String[] data`. In my log page, I need to have the id as well as the row present in the file.

Currently, if I try to print then am getting values like  `[Ljava.lang.String;@1152e94`, my question is how can i get actual list of array elements like `[20, 11, Clothing, TShirts, Abercombie, Gap]`?

Tried using default `toString()` but still it give same `LString` data.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.toString(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to obtain something more human-readable.

Comment: I get values as  `[Ljava.lang.String;@1152e94`

Comment: yes, i got the point, after using `Arrays.toString()` am able to print values fine without any kind of issues.

Answer (score 11):

use `Arrays.toString(array);` it will work

Answer (score 1):

May be: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) ?

```
String[] data = [20,11,Clothing,TShirts,Abercombie,Gap]
Arrays.toString(data);
```

or

```
Arrays.deepToString(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a line of the csv file and call String.split(",") on the line which will return you an array of each seperate string in the line you just read then you can simply loop through the array and print them out as you need.

```
String csvLine = scanner.nextLine();

String[] values = csvLine.split(",");
for(String s : values){
  System.out.println(s);
}
```